# Failed to create, join or add replica to availability group in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, failover

I have a 2 node FCI and a standalone SQL Server installation on a non FCI node. I have been automating the configuration/installation of FCIs, AGs, and DB Replicas which has worked fine up to now in all of my testing.

Today I am getting the error below when I execute:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP [AGName]
WITH (AUTOMATED_BACKUP_PREFERENCE = SECONDARY)
FOR 
REPLICA ON N'Node3\ReadOnly' WITH (ENDPOINT_URL = N'TCP://Node3-blah.blah.com:5022', FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL, AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT, SESSION_TIMEOUT = 10, BACKUP_PRIORITY = 50, PRIMARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = ALL), SECONDARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = ALL)),
    N'Primary/Primary' WITH (ENDPOINT_URL = N'TCP://primary.blah.com:5022', FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL, AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT, SESSION_TIMEOUT = 10, BACKUP_PRIORITY = 50, PRIMARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = ALL), SECONDARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = NO));
GO
```

Error:

> Msg 19405, Level 16, State 17, Line 3
>   Failed to create, join or add replica to availability group 'AGName', because node 'Node3' is a possible owner for both replica 'Node3\ReadOnly' and 'Primary/Primary'. If one replica is failover cluster instance, remove the overlapped node from its possible owners and try again.

Node 3 is *not* part of the FCI.  It has a standalone installation of SQL Server and it is not listed as a possible owner.

If I attempt to failover to Node 3 the FCI informs me that it is not a possible owner.

I'm not sure what caused this.  I did failover using the FCI between node 1 and 2 several days earlier.  I did remove the listener this time to test that, as that was the last thing I was working on.  Any thoughts?

I could just tear down the FCI and have the automation recreate it but I wanted to try to solve this without doing that just in case this happens in prod one day.  We should be able to evict the node from the WSFC and re-add it as well but I don't want to bug our ops team which has to do that.  We will be tearing down the entire cluster and letting it build from scratch before releasing it though.

**Edit. This is the output from the FCI node:**

```
select * from sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes

NodeName    status  status_description  is_current_owner
---------------------------------------------------------
SQNodeL001-LA   0   up  1
SQNodeL002-LA   0   up  0
SQLNode003-LA   0   up  0
```

The output from the standalone is empty.  It is part of the WSFC but not FCI or AG yet.

The powershell output shows us that all 3 can be owner nodes which is odd.

```
ClusterObject                                               OwnerNodes
-------------                                               ----------
SQL Server (Instance)                                           {SQNodeL001-LA, SQNodeL002-LA, SQNodeL003-LA}
```

From the GUI it does not have node 3 selected as a preferred owner.  Pardon for making minor changes and removing the names.  The first node name is all in lowercase.  The other 2 are in upper case.  It looks like I might need to do all this in powershell to get the accurate data, haven't gotten to automating that step yet.  That'll be next sprint.

**Edit 2 - solved:**

Thanks to Sean's PowerShell query I was able to see that it is still listed as a owner in PowerShell although it is not in the GUI. I removed it using `get-clusterresource "sql server (instance)" | set-clusterownernode -Owners node1 node2` and it worked.  Thanks Sean!

[image]

Comment: It was likely a mistake that was not caught but can probably be corrected without a tear down.  Try this explanation at: http://www.lifeasbob.com/MainBlog,month,2013-12.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I've checked a few times and just rechecked that it is not a possible owner of the FCI, I even did a restart on the nodes but to no avail.  This one is a interesting problem. It's almost as if it's getting that info from some other location than the Failover Cluster Manager.

Comment: What collation and language is the windows cluster? Do you have mixed upper and lower case node names or all upper/all lower?

Comment: No WSFC node can host – or even be possible owners of – multiple instances, whether standalone or clustered, that are involved in the same Availability Group. You get that error message - see [this blog post from Aaron Bertrand](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/system-configuration/troubleshooting-alwayson)

Comment: Ali - Hope all is well bud, long time no see - can you update the question with the output from the following? `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes` also in powershell `get-clusterownernode -resource "FCIInstanceName"`

Comment: @SeanGallardy it's great to see you, last I heard you got out from the east coast!  If so welcome. Great to have you out here on this side.  You're right, the 3rd node (read only AG Replica node) has it's names in caps, the rest are lower case.  Collation and language is the default English. I'll post results to the question now.

Comment: Hi @Kin  Thanks.  I had gone through that but the odd thing is the 3rd node should not be a failover node in this config.  It worked fine until I removed the AG to automate creating it, then it stopped working.  Something might have changed in the week I had it configured perhaps.  Not sure what.

Comment: @SeanGallardy your powershell command get-clusterownernode led me to the right direction.  I did a get-clusterresource "sql server (instance)" | set-clusterownernode -Owners node1/node2 and I was able to add the AG.  I'm not sure why the WSFC considered the 3rd read only node as part of the FCI but it wasn't checked in the GUI.  If you can make a quick answer Sean with the command or a quick explanation so I can mark it as the correct answer.  Am I looking at the wrong spot on the GUI for potential available nodes?

Comment: @AliRazeghi The gui is... good for certain things. Get used to powershell with clusters though, most things the gui doesn't even show (nor will it). I'll make an answer which was to include the set-clusterownernode but you beat me to it :)

Comment: Absolutely!  The consistency created is worth it's weight in gold alone.  All the automation is done in powershell and dsc. I was working my way backwards though and didn't get to get familiar with the cluster commands yet.  Was surprised to see it show different though!  I think perhaps it is being added as a possible owner due to it being added to the AG.  I'm going to test and try to break it to see what happens. Thanks again Sean! I'll look for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Msg 19405, Level 16, State 17, Line 3 Failed to create, join or add
>   replica to availability group 'AGName', because node 'Node3' is a
>   possible owner for both replica 'Node3\ReadOnly' and
>   'Primary/Primary'. If one replica is failover cluster instance, remove
>   the overlapped node from its possible owners and try again.

This happens for two main reasons that I've witnessed.

**Reason #1 - The resource/group is set to have ownership on the node in error**

Sometimes (for a multitude of reasons) resources and resource groups in windows clustering won't always have the same ownership. The best way to diagnose this error is to first check to see what SQL Server (which calls windows clustering APIs) thinks the cluster nodes are:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes
```

Once we know what is in the cluster, check via **Powershell** to see what the cluster thinks the ownership is for the FCI:

```
Get-ClusterOwnerNode -Resource "SQLFCIInstanceName"
```

This will return the nodes that could own the cluster resource. Chances are it'll include the node name of a node that **we** know shouldn't really be there.

To fix this, run the following **powershell** command:

```
Get-ClusterResource -Name "SQLFCIInstanceName" | Set-ClusterOwnerNode -Owners NodeName1,NodeName2
```

Double check by running the first powershell command to check ownership, then try to add the replica to the AG again.

**Reason #2 - Node Names + Language != Node Names**

If the language used wasn't US_English there would be a good chance that the node names (when compared to each other) wouldn't necessarily compare properly. This would cause a whole bunch of other issues (and it does) with the cluster outside of the AG.

This can be tested by taking the node names, converting them to upper or lower and the comparing them against themselves. Sounds like it should always work... but some languages have special characters that don't do the UPPER and LOWER conversions well.